# How to access parent module in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have a general-purpose loader for fetching records from a database:

```
defmodule Loader do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote location: :keep, bind_quoted: [schema: opts[:schema]] do

      def one(id), do: unquote(schema) |> Repo.get(id)
      def all,     do: unquote(schema) |> Repo.all
    end
  end
end
```

and particular loaders fro specific schemas:

```
defmodule Location.Loader do
  use Loader, schema: Location
end
```

Is there any way to communicate with "used" module in some other way e.g. `__MODULE__.parent`?

Comment: What is it that you would like to do? You can refer to the module by name like any other module.

Comment: The thing you are trying to do looks a little bit overcomplicated. I would also like to know what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: As you can see, I want to have access in `Loader` to `Location` which is a "top" module of a module where `Loader` is used.

Comment: What is the reason you want to access `Loader`. What do you mean by "access" - call functions? If so you can call public functions with `Loader.some_function()`. There is no way to call private functions from another module.

Comment: I want to use `Location.Loader.all` or `Location.Loader.one(123)`. The thing is that I want to know somehow in general `Loader`, the name of module it is invoked from e.g. `Location.Loader`. I achieved that by passing this in `opts` but i wonder if there's any other way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `__MODULE__` from inside the `quote` of `Loader.__using__`, and use `Module.split/1`, `Enum.drop/2`, and `Module.concat/1` to get the parent module.

```
defmodule Loader do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote location: :keep, bind_quoted: [schema: opts[:schema]] do
      @parent_module __MODULE__ |> Module.split |> Enum.drop(-1) |> Module.concat
      def one(id), do: IO.puts("#{@parent_module}:one:#{id}")
      def all,     do: IO.puts("#{@parent_module}:all")
    end
  end
end

defmodule Location.Loader do
  use Loader
end

Location.Loader.one 123
Location.Loader.all
```

prints

```
Elixir.Location:one:123
Elixir.Location:all
```

But, I would recommend *not* using this and using your original code as it's more explicit, and from my experience, considered more idiomatic.